# duplicity fails with timeout

Tags: ubuntu-one, deja-dup

After one hour of backup with deja-dup, it failed with this exception.
Is this a network problem on my side ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1403, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1396, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1247, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1007, in ProcessCommandLine
    backup, local_pathname = set_backend(args[0], args[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 900, in set_backend
    globals.backend = backend.get_backend(bend)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 158, in get_backend
    return _backends[pu.scheme](pu)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/u1backend.py", line 74, in __init__
    self.create_volume()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 323, in iterate
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/u1backend.py", line 161, in create_volume
    answer = auth.request(self.volume_uri, http_method="PUT")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch/ubuntuone/couch/auth.py", line 152, in request
    url, method=http_method, headers=headers, body=request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1444, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1196, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1132, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 889, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
timeout: timed out
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a `timeout` error from the `socket.py` Python module, it probably is a network issue.

However, you shouldn't have to look at terminal output to notice errors, Déjà Dup should report them to you in a user-friendly graphical dialog or notification. This could be a bug, in which case, you should [report it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).